# High training / valid / test accuracy, but low accuracy when using model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I trained a model that classifies number images like mnist problem.

So I prepared a dataset with 600, 120, 120 images for train, valid, test set at each classes.

After hours of training, the train accuracy was 0.9981 and valid accuracy was 0.9992.
The test accuracy was 0.9992.

However when I used this trained model to predict images that was used at training before, the average accuracy was way much lower that training... nearly 70%.

I'm so confused because if this was due to overfitting, the trained model should predict images that were used at training at high accuracy... but it's accuracy is low for new images and test set images both.

why is this happening? Is this because the number of dataset is too small or something else?
below is training result.

```
...
Epoch 49/50
280/280 [==============================] - 19s 68ms/step - loss: 0.0077 - acc: 0.9971 - val_loss: 0.0125 - val_acc: 0.9992
Epoch 50/50
280/280 [==============================] - 19s 69ms/step - loss: 0.0058 - acc: 0.9981 - val_loss: 0.0126 - val_acc: 0.9992

-- Evaluate --
acc: 99.92%
```

--EDIT--
below is model architecture

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(width, height, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I'm using this trained model by deploying it with tensorflow-serving in my server. I sampled out some images that were used at training, and posted the data to tensorflow-serving api. And the predict accuracy was low.

Comment: The bias of your model is probably high which makes it poor at generalising to unseen examples. To improve this, you can try reducing the complexity of your model (fewer weights, or add dropout layers) or add more training data. It's normal for your model to perform less well on data it hasn't seen before than the data its trained on.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the weights and parameters from the trained model when calling the model to make the prediction?

Comment: I'm not too sure @TeymourAldridge he said he predicted on images that were used during training. In this particular case, overfitting would be 'good'

Comment: Oh. My bad. I see that the problem is more complicated than I originally thought and probably due to technical error as you've suggested.

Comment: @CeliusStingher yes you're right... I guessed that if this was due to overfitting, then it should at least predict test set images best... but it didn't...

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to evaluate the model and finding the surprisingly low accuracy?

Comment: @TeymourAldridge I already used dropout layer and am sure that i used correct weight from trained model...

Comment: Yes, please add the architecture of your network so we can check it. Together with the code where you make your predict.

Comment: Predicting on training images when the model is overfitted should yield extremely high accuracy.

Comment: @CeliusStingher I added the architecture of model. I didn't test the whole training set image to the trained model. I just sampled about 10 images and tested it.

Comment: I have a few questions, 1. Does your dataset contain class imbalance? 2. Is there any knowledge leak using same image in train/test/validation? 3. Are the train/test/valid samples very similar? 4. What about using stratified k fold and different metrics? 5. Is the data scaled/normalized properly?

Comment: @B200011011 Thanks! I solved this by checking all the possible reasons. It was due to the wrong input_shape ordering when constructing model architecture. I had run learning with width and height orders switched...